# Message=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request

Tags: web-services

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open log for source 'ExceptionManagerInternalException'. You may not have write access. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.OpenForWrite(String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32 eventID, UInt16 category, EventLogEntryType type, String[] strings, Byte[] rawData, String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String source, String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
   at CTL.COM.ExceptionManagement.DefaultPublisher.WriteToLog(String entry, EventLogEntryType type)
   at CTL.COM.ExceptionManagement.DefaultPublisher.Publish(Exception exception, NameValueCollection additionalInfo, NameValueCollection configSettings)
   at CTL.COM.ExceptionManagement.ExceptionManager.PublishInternalException(Exception exception, NameValueCollection additionalInfo)
   at CTL.COM.ExceptionManagement.ExceptionManager.Publish(Exception exception, NameValueCollection additionalInfo)
   at CTL.COM.Services.Util.Utilities.HandleExceptions(Exception ex, APIResponse xmlResponse)
   at CTL.COM.Services.Util.AcquireTicketImplementation.AcquireTicket(AcquireTicketRequest xmlRequest, AcquireTicketResponse xmlResponse)
   at CTL.COM.Services.Prime.Issuer.WebServices.PrimeIssuerServices.AcquireTicket(AcquireTicketRequest xmlRequest)
```

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Any ideas? Help me please?

Comment: I tried this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f5ad26c7-7891-4b9b-aee4-b64b68ab4cde/web-service-has-no-right-to-write-event-log-on-windows-server-2008-r2-and-sharepoint-2007-with-sp2 but not worked